# Trying commands in bash for a limited number of times

Tags: bash, shell-script

Wanted to retry a command  in function. For testing I have written the wrong command (`lsss`).
It should try for 5 times & fail, but it stuck in infinite loop.

```
#!/bin/bash

RETRY () {

        Attempt=0
        Max_Attempts=5
        CMD=$1
        while [ $Attempt -lt $Max_Attempts ]
        do
            $CMD

        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
           echo "succeeded on Attempt $Attempt" >> /tmp/err.txt
            break
        else
                 Attempt=$( expr $Attempt + 1 )
        echo  "Command failed. Attempting  $Attempt/$Max_Attempts" >> /tmp/err.txt
                 sleep 2
        fi
done

}

LIST () {

        lsss  # COMMAND WRITTEN WRONGLY FOR TESTING

        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
         echo "SUCCESS" 
        else
        RETRY LIST

        echo "FAILED" 
        fi
}
LIST
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

There's no question in your "question". I assume the question is "why?".

Whenever `LIST` is run, `lsss` fails, so `RETRY LIST` is invoked. Then (from the inside of `RETRY`) `LIST` (as `$CMD`) is run again and we can explain from the start.

Bash never gets past `$CMD` inside `RETRY`. Your two functions call each other, they stack more and more; none of them really exits.

---

I think your entire approach is flawed. I don't know what's the exact purpose but to "try a command for a limited number of times", this may be your starting point:

```
(max=5; for n in `seq 1 $max`; do your_command && break; done)
```

A subshell is used to keep `$max` out of the current shell. Note the whole command returns quite sane exit code.

Comment: how will   I pass  $CMD  in  RETRY ?

Comment: @zim `LIST` (invoked from the inside of `RETRY` as `$CMD`) must return, only then Bash will continue beyond `$CMD` line. But `LIST` invokes *another* `RETRY` and waits for *it* to return. This `RETRY` invokes *another* `LIST` and so on. I think your entire approach is flawed.

Comment: i got  it. it worked , but  can we modify the script so that we can use the RETRY  function.

Comment: @zim We are not a script writing service nor a forum, this is Q&A site. You haven't even ask a question in the body of your "question"; I had to guess. What keeps you from writing my "starting point" in a form of a function? If you encounter some specific problem with this, then you may ask another question. But do your research first, show some research effort.